# Managing a list of data.frames based on multiple data.frame attributes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, if-statement

I have a list of dataframes that I need to check for three different conditions including corresponding handling of dataframes:

1. For dataframes with one row: Return the dataframe
2. For dataframes with > 1 row & not identical last and second last rows regarding my choice of columns: Just return the unique rows based on my choice of columns
3. For dataframes with > 1 row & identical last and second last rows based on my choice of columns:
   For all the rows of the dataframe but the last two, return unique rows regarding my choice of columns and append the last two rows to the resulting df

Here's a reprex of what I tried:

```
library (dplyr)

id <- c(1,1,1,1) 
var1 <- c(1,2,3,3)
var2 <- c('one','two','three','three')
df1 <- data.frame(id,var1,var2)

id <- c(2,2,2,2) 
var1 <- c(2,2,3,3)
var2 <- c('one','one','three','four')
df2 <- data.frame(id,var1,var2)

id <- 3
var1 <- 2
var2 <- "four"
df3 <- data.frame(id,var1,var2)

list_dfs <- list (df1, df2, df3)

lapply (list_dfs, function (df) {
  if (nrow(df)==1) { # condition 1
    df
  } else if ((nrow(df)>1) & (df[nrow(df),2:3]!=df[nrow(df)-1,2:3])) { # condition 2
    df <- df %>% 
      distinct (var1, var2, .keep_all = TRUE)
    df
  } else if ((nrow(df)>1) & (df[nrow(df),2:3]==df[nrow(df)-1,2:3])) { # condition 3
    dfpart1 <- head(df, -2) %>%
      distinct (var1, var2, .keep_all = TRUE)
    dfpart2 <- tail(df, 2)
    dfs <- rbind (dfpart1, dfpart2)
    dfs
  }
}) %>%  do.call(rbind, .)
```

In my list of dfs there are no dfs without any rows, so I haven't `else` at the end. My problem is that the vectors returned for conditions 2 & 3 are > 1 which `if` is not designed for (Error in if...the condition has length > 1). But what would be a feasible alternative, for instance, using `ifelse` or another approach?

My desired output for this example is:

```
  id var1  var2
  1    1   one
  1    2   two
  1    3   three
  1    3   three
  2    2   one
  2    3   three
  2    3   four
  3    2   four
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
df[nrow(df),2:3]!=df[nrow(df)-1,2:3])
```

But you can see that you are searching for a condition with more than one element, and `if` statement is comparing two values, which are elements from columns 2 to 3.
So you need something that can compare that two elements, and then if they are not equal, a `FALSE` (or `TRUE` depending on your needs) is returned.
So you can use `all()`:

```
df_test <- rbind(c(2,3,1,5),c(2,3,1,5),c(1,1,1,1))
```

out:

```
> df_test
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    3    1    5
[2,]    2    3    1    5
[3,]    1    1    1    1
```

and then you can use for example

```
> all(df_test[1,3:4]==df_test[2,3:4])
[1] TRUE
```

which will return a boolean, which is a must if you are working with `if` statement

Comment: Using ```all``` is not sufficient for condition 2. But your suggestion put me on the right track. A combination of ```any(df[nrow(df),2:3]!=df[nrow(df)-1,2:3])``` for condition 2 and ```all(df[nrow(df),2:3]==df[nrow(df)-1,2:3])``` for condition 3 does the job. Can you update your suggestion so that I can make it the accepted answer?